# Opportunity Name Label Not Showing Correctly

Tags: visualforce, sobjecttype, label

I want to show the Opportunity Name label on VF page using the following code.

```
{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.Name.label}
```

[image]

The label is 'Opportunity Name,'
but instead of showing 'Opportunity Name', it shows 'Name'.

[image]

Could anyone please tell me what might have caused this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that SFDC treats `Opportunity.Name` label inconsistently depending on usage (reports, list views, standard page layout).  My hypothesis is that this is done to disambiguate from `Account Name` as both `Opportunity Name` and `Account Name` appear together on most Opportunity reports.

If you go to SFDC Workbench and look at the metadata that will be fetched by `{!$ObjectType.Opportunity.fields.Name.label}` as shown below, you will see the result will be `Name`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I went to the workbench and checked. I'd be very happy if SF fixed either of the labels to make them at least similar. This is misleading and inconvenient, in case I want to use the 'Opportunity Name' label, to create a custom label for something that has to be existing.